# Is it okay to reproduce an answer that I wrote from another SE site?

Tags: discussion

A [recent question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/104093/17928) is essentially identical to [another question asked on the MathEducators SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/130/29).

I wrote [an answer to the MathEducators SE question](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/145/29); would it be inappropriate to copy/paste that same answer to this site?

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better if you were to explain that you've answered a similar question elsewhere on SE, include a link, and summarize the key points of your answer.